# how to insert image tag to html string?

Tags: html, reactjs, image, text

i have problem inserting image into html string. I use react js. I retrieve the html string from the database.
the example of html string is like this:

```
<div align = "justify"> <font face = "Trebuchet MS"> Various regional economic indicators in the third quarter of 2013 tended to slow in aggregate terms. <br> Indications of improvement in exports that are beginning to appear in most regions are still restrained by relative conditions <br> low commodity prices on the global market are not expected to offset the slowdown in household consumption and investment. Slowing economic growth is predicted to take place in most areas in Sumatra and Jakarta, <br> while Java and Eastern Indonesia (KTI) are projected to show slight growth. <br> <br> Meanwhile, inflation in all regions is recorded higher during the quarter under review as the impact of <br> from the policy on the increase in the price of subsidized fuel oil (BBM) at the end of June 2013 and <br> disruption in food supply. Despite this, inflationary pressures began to ease at the end of the quarter under review as food supply constraints began to be overcome, particularly for <br> commodities onions and chilies, as well as additional supply of imported meat. At the end of the <br> quarter, food inflationary pressure was even lower in several regions in Sulawesi, Maluku and Nusa Tenggara due to deep price corrections for fresh fish commodities. <br> <br> <span style = "font-size: 11pt; color: rgb (31, 73, 125);" lang = "IN"> The material can be downloaded from the website address Bank Indonesia official. </span> <br> </div>
```

and i want to add an image in the middle of the html string. does anyone have a solution?

Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` . In your case it would be like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const test =
  '<div align = "justify"> <font face = "Trebuchet MS"> Various regional economic indicators in the third quarter of 2013 tended to slow in aggregate terms. <br> Indications of improvement in exports that are beginning to appear in most regions are still restrained by relative conditions <br> low commodity prices on the global market are not expected to offset the slowdown in household consumption and investment. Slowing economic growth is predicted to take place in most areas in Sumatra and Jakarta, <br> while Java and Eastern Indonesia (KTI) are projected to show slight growth. <br> <br> Meanwhile, inflation in all regions is recorded higher during the quarter under review as the impact of <br> from the policy on the increase in the price of subsidized fuel oil (BBM) at the end of June 2013 and <br> disruption in food supply. Despite this, inflationary pressures began to ease at the end of the quarter under review as food supply constraints began to be overcome, particularly for <br> commodities onions and chilies, as well as additional supply of imported meat. At the end of the <br> quarter, food inflationary pressure was even lower in several regions in Sulawesi, Maluku and Nusa Tenggara due to deep price corrections for fresh fish commodities. <br> <br> <span style = "font-size: 11pt; color: rgb (31, 73, 125);" lang = "IN"> The material can be downloaded from the website address Bank Indonesia official. </span> <br> </div>';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: test }}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Note:** dangerouslySetInnerHTML can be dangerous if you dont know what html is going to inject.

Better solution would be to use [`this`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) package:

```
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";


const withSanitzedHtml = DOMPurify.sanitize(test);
```

**Note:** For adding image you can split you string where you want to append and simply join again. Just like do on normal js.

Here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-html-inject-76vlo)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how to do a split in the middle of text. For example, there are 2 paragraphs, I want to split them between the two paragraphs.

Comment: Can you update your requirement in the sandbox link?

Comment: @Zenryo I have updated my sandbox link. Is it something like this you want?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Flowers in Chania">
```

For more details study: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Comment: I think the problem statement is about how to insert in `html` which is already coming as  a string and render in react

Comment: @ShubhamVerma yeah, ur right... thank you for clarifying